# After I press rebirth i want to add 10 to 2 totals. Not working

Tags: javascript, html

So Im working on a game and I want when i press rebirth for hitpoints and manapoints to go up by 10.

i've tried a few things including following what i did to increase the cookie count but nothing seems to be working.

This is my html code:

```
<span id="cookies">0</span>
                <br />
                <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
                <br />
                Cost: 50 <button id="BigClickBtn" 
onclick="cookieClick(50)">BigClick</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span> <button 
id="cursorCostBtn" onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="catCost">50</span> <button 
onclick="buyCat()" id="catCostBtn">Buy Cat</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="dogCost">100</span> <button 
onclick="buyDog()" id="dogCostBtn">Buy Dog</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="humanCost">200</span> <button 
onclick="buyHuman()" id="humanCostBtn">Buy Human</button>
                <br />
                Cost: <span id="rebirthCost">10</span> <button 
onclick="buyRebirth()" id="rebirthCostBtn">Rebirth</button>
                <br />
                Hp:<span id="HitPoints">0</span> Mp:<span 
id="ManaPoints">0</span>
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
}
var rebirths = 0;
var HitPoints = 0;
var ManaPoints = 0;

function buyRebirth() {
    var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.5, rebirths));
    if (cookies >= rebirthCost) {
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
     if (rebirths>1)
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost;
        document.getElementById('rebirths').innerHTML = rebirths; 
//updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates 
the number of cookies for the user
        document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = Hitpoints;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;

    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.5, rebirths)); //works out 
the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('rebirthCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates 
the cursor cost for the user
    checkCursor()
}
```

I expect http://prntscr.com/nrpjjk  my hp and mp to update to Hp:10 and Mp:10 when i press rebirth. at the moment the actual output is Hp:0 and Mp:0 (no change).

Comment: Reference error: `Hitpoints` is not defined, and that breaks the rest of the code. I.e. a typo ...

Comment: sorry i missed some stuff fixing now

Comment: as in i forgot to put that part in. i had that in my code

Comment: That's not what I meant, you've mistyped `HitPoints` as `Hitpoints` on the line the value is put to `innerHTML` of `#HitPoints`.

Comment: i fixed that still no increase in mana or hp when i press rebirth

Comment: You specify `document.getElementById('rebirths').innerHTML = rebirths;`, but I don't see an element with the ID of "rebirths".

Comment: I haven't fully gotten to the bottom of it, but there's something wrong going on with your `var rebirthCost`. If I make some changes to it and some other things, I can get it to work... somewhat. I've stripped it down into a working example here, however it still has some issues. Have a look -- https://jsfiddle.net/w1sqtmj2/11/

Comment: You also need to address the `document.getElementById` call for the nonexistent "rebirths" element.  Leaving it in as is caused it to not run. Some problems also exist with the `var nextCost` section, as removing it was also necessary for the program to run.

Comment: sorry im really new at this. is document.getElementById the equivalent to in python like rebirths.set(rebirth.get()+10)? i did the nextcost var so everytime the button is pressed the price will increase. i can post a pic of more code to show you that i have a working function. i tried to follow the format for the working function but it didnt turn out the same http://prntscr.com/ns0ctd